# M2Crypto: Trying to decrypt SMIME string. Getting no content type Error

Tags: python, encryption, m2crypto, smime

I'm trying to decrypt an SMIME encrypted message (encrypted in JavaScript using PKI.js library), which looks like this:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m;
 smime-type=enveloped-data
Content-Description: Enveloped Data
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Example S/MIME encrypted message
Date: Sun, 13 May 2018 23:53:48 +0000
Message-Id: <1526255628125-055f663b-fd554ae9-1ed33cf1@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
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```

And I do it the following way:

```
from M2Crypto import BIO, SMIME, X509

def decrypt(s):
    mime = SMIME.SMIME()

    with open("tmp.p7", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
        p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7("tmp.p7")
    return mime.decrypt(p7)
```

What I get is the following message:

```
File "/Users/Adam/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/M2Crypto/SMIME.py", line 113, in smime_load_pkcs7
    p7_ptr, bio_ptr = m2.smime_read_pkcs7(bio)
M2Crypto.SMIME.SMIME_Error: no content type
```

If I do

```
with open("tmp.p7", 'w') as f:
            f.write(s)
```

instead, the result is the same... that no content type error message.

Can anybody, please, help me?

Comment: Have you tried closing the file first `f.close()`

Comment: Yes, then it says `M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7_Error: bad decrypt`.

Comment: That could caused by using the wrong key.

Comment: So you think the problem is not in the code?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is a full mail message, not just the *CMS or PKCS#7 content*.

Strip off the mail headers until you have only the base 64 encoding left (starting after the newline) and try again.

---

You can see your data [here (online JavaScript ASN.1 decoder)](https://lapo.it/asn1js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

These are very new algorithms (RSA-OAEP with MGF1 / SHA-512 and AES), but in the end they only encrypt a 16 byte ciphertext, which is indeed not identified in any way. So in that sense the content type **is** missing, maybe you can give it as an argument somehow.

Not posted as a comment as it would not fit, your data is in the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean this? `MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<encoded content>`

Comment: Yeah, try without *all* the headers, including To: / Subject: etc. The OpenSSL version of the function seems to accept base 64, so...

Comment: when I try with no header, only the encrypted content, it says `no content type`.

Comment: You could try to decode to binary using OpenSSL command line. After that we'll have to parse the input to see if anything is wrong. I'm trying to avoid that :)

Comment: hmm... how can I do that?

Comment: Thank you... Ok, I decoded it and when I execute cat, it displays `0?`.

Comment: Also, when I open it in PyCharm, it says the file was loaded in the wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'

Comment: The PyCharm output: `0�`

Comment: It's binary and thus not printable. Try openssl asn1parse -inform DER

Comment: I did `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in encrypt.p7` and I got `    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  73 prim: appl [ 13 ]       
   75:d=0  hl=2 l= 101 cons: appl [ 20 ]       
Error in encoding
3782:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:asn1_lib.c:147:`

Comment: Oh, hey, maybe you are having a badly encoded or partial CMS structure there. Lemme check. Hmm, the last 4 bytes should not be part of the CMS structure. Could you try and remove them from the binary / DER file and try again?

Comment: Actually, hope you know that I closed the file before I loaded pkcs_7 a it says `bad decrypt`